# Cookie not created if requested from browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api, session-cookies

I'm trying to create a cookie by adding cookie to response header. If i send request from Postman the cookie is created, but if the request is sent from browser the cookie is not created. Same goes in case of reading cookie. Here is my code for creating cookie.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateAndSendCookie(string username, string password)
{
    var validuser = await _service.validateUser(username, password);
        if (validuser != null)
        {
            var user = await _service.getUserById(validuser.id);

            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
            var nvCollection = new NameValueCollection();

            var javaScriptSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            nvCollection.Add("user", javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(user));
            foreach (Orgnization item in user.organizations)
            {
                nvCollection.Add("organizaton", javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(item));
            }

            var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("PLAY_SESSION", nvCollection);
            cookie.Path = "/";
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            var cookieHeaderValue = new List<CookieHeaderValue>() { cookie };
            resp.Headers.AddCookies(cookieHeaderValue);
            string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(user);
            resp.Content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            return resp;
}
```

and here is the code to reading the cookie

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CheckCookie()
{
    CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("PLAY_SESSION").FirstOrDefault();
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}
```

Can anyone spot-out the issue in this code.

Comment: Is he cookie in the Header?  A cookie only exist is a previous session created one.  So it may be normal for the cookie not to exist.  So reading the cookie may fail.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to trace the http messages so help get code working.

Comment: Cookie is in the header and will be created on client when response is received by the client. On subsequent request the cookie should be available to the application. Keep in mind that this implementation is done in WebAPI

Comment: Only if you send a good request and get back a good response.  if you haven't gotten through the code once you would not have a cookie.

Comment: My cookie create call send me the response with Set-Cookie header and the value is properly set to the cookie but i'm unable to see it in cookies list in browser.

Comment: What is the life time of cookie.  Is it expiring or have a bad time value?

Comment: Cookie that i'm creating will be expired after the browser is closed (session).

Comment: Maybe the cookies are expiring before you check in the browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132768/discussion-between-zeb-ur-rehman-and-jdweng).